# Brunch: Use //# instead of //@ to indicate source map URL

Tags: brunch, source-maps

How can I set up brunch to use `//#` instead `//@` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.sourceMaps = 'new'`, that's it.

**edit 13 oct** now brunch automatically uses new syntax since v1.7.8

Comment: Is this in the documentation?

Comment: No. This is a temporary solution. When Chrome with new source maps syntax will be stable (I think it should be now), new Brunch release will auto-switch to //# and then old syntax will be available under `'old'` param.